# VBA Identify duplicate value in column and select value in row

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns in my spreadsheet. If the value in column A repeats, then I want to get the corresponding value in column B for both these values and compare them. If there is a difference, write Yes in column C.

Example, code 123456 appears twice in column A, and there is a difference so I have to write "Yes" in column C. On the other hand, 999999 appears twice but there is no difference so I have to write "No".

```
Item_code   sale_price      Difference
123456   $        123.56    Yes
999999   $    1,542.00      No
598745   $    8,455.00      NA
123456   $        130.99    Yes
546892   $        562.00    NA
999999   $    1,542.00      No
```

Giving below the code, not sure why it is not identifying the next occurrence of the same value and getting the relative value from column B. It just keeps getting me the first occurrence.

```vb
Sub compare_dollars_Click()

item_row = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For item_counter = 2 To item_row

      get_input = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & item_counter).Value

If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C:C"), get_input) > 1 Then

                var1 = Range("B" & item_counter)
                MsgBox ("Sale Price" & "   " & var1 & "  " & item_counter)
End If

check_threshold (get_input)

Next item_counter

End Sub


Sub check_threshold(get_input)

Set repeat_cell_address = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C:C").Find(get_input, lookat:=xlPart)

newrow = repeat_cell_address.Row

                MsgBox (newrow)
                var2 = Range("B" & newrow)
                MsgBox ("Second occurrence of item code" & "   " & var2 & "  " & newrow)

End Sub
```

Comment: You could do this with COUNTIFS and bypass VBA.

Comment: Thanks, but can you please elaborate on how it can be done using my dataset?

Comment: Why do you want to mark them like this? Unless this is your end goal, perhaps there is a simpler way of accomplishing your real goal.  What version of Excel?

Comment: Based on whether there is a duplicate value, I have to do certain checks on the figures and if they are out of certain range, then mark them as such in the column C. I couldn't think of any other way of doing it besides vba. Pease let me know if you have a simpler solution. Thanks much.

Comment: Sounds like you make those calculations a part of the `COUNTIF(s)` formula, and dispense with VBA entirely.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just checking that an item code has more than one different price, this should do it.

In C2 and copied down:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,A2)=1,"NA",IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,A2,$B$2:$B$7,B2)=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,A2),"No","Yes"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out and provide an update.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested you can do this without VBA if your happy to using the `COUNTIFS` formula. This is just **A** solution.

It would look like this:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$10,$A2)=1,"NA",IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10,$A2,$B$2:$B$10,"<>"&$B2)>0,"Yes","No"))
```

Put that into cell `C2` and drag it to the bottom. Obviously you will need to change the `$A$10` and `$B$10` to whatever the last row is.

This checks if there are any matching item codes that do not have the same sale price as the row that the formula is on.

If you really want a VBA solution that's fine.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out and provide an update. The reason I was going VBA route is because of the calculations that I have to do to check whether the values are in a range and depending on that, the result should be given in column C.